# Query two columns that reference each other, how to?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: r]

So Having this table, how would I go to get

Code is PK

the name and next to it, the name of the boss, I have no idea how would I get the  name out of the boss code?

Comment: Are you trying to get the name of boss in code id?

Comment: Exactly, so the result would be like 

name, boss_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have there a self relation.

You just have to think about it as it was another table.

Just use a join (left or inner, depends what you need)

```sql
SELECT e.code, e.name, b.code, b.name from table_name e
join table_name b on e.boss = b.code
```

Comment: Great,  this is what I was looking for, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

You need a left self join:

```
select t1.name, t2.name bossname
from tablename t1 left join tablename t2
on t1.boss = t2.code
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT C.code, e.name, b.code, b.name FROM **TABLE1** C
JOIN **TABLE2** B ON B.boss = C.code